# Get round up double from decimal in Swift (Algorithm)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to achieve several number suggestion. But I couldn't find the algorithm on how to achieve it.

I am working on sales app that display the total price of selected items, and there will be 3 total amount suggestions based on the total price. These 3 total amounts are round up from the total price of selected items

So basically the user can choose either one of the suggested amount, solely for better user experience.

In my country there are 5 types of bank notes :

```
$1, $5, $10, $20, $50, $100
```

For example

```
Total Price: 307.40
First suggestion: 308.00
Second suggestion: 310.00
Third suggestion: 350.00

Total Price: 14.54
First suggestion: 15.00
Second suggestion: 20.00
Third suggestion: 50.00

Total Price: 131.82
First suggestion: 132.00
Second suggestion: 140.00
Third suggestion: 150.00
```

So basically, the suggested amount must be based on the bank notes. The examples above are just to describe the test case, it must not be as exactly same as above.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve such function?

Thanks! Really appreciate any help given.

Comment: So your question is how to round up to the next integer or to the next multiple of 10 or 50?

Comment: It's kind of vague... what's exactly the question?

Comment: @AhmadF updated question. does it make sense now?

Comment: @MartinR the first suggestion will be the round up to the next integer, and for the second and third, it can be multiple of 10 or 50.

Answer (score 6):

A floating point number is rounded up to the next integral value with

```
let price = 307.40;
let integralPrice = price.rounded(.up)    // 308.00
```

Rounding up to the next multiple of 5, 10, 50, ... can be done
by *scaling,* for example:

```
let multipleOfTen   = (price / 10).rounded(.up) * 10    // 310
let multipleOfFifty = (price / 50).rounded(.up) * 50    // 350
```

And for multiples which are different from the given price
and different from each other:

```
let price = 109.0;
let integralPrice = price.nextUp.rounded(.up)   // 110
let multipleOfTen   = (integralPrice.nextUp / 10).rounded(.up) * 10   // 120
let multipleOfFifty = (multipleOfTen.nextUp / 50).rounded(.up) * 50   // 150
```

Here [`nextUp`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/1847593-nextup) is used to increment a floating point number by "a tiny bit".

Comment: Sir, you are really a life saver! Thanks so much!

Comment: Sir, what if the total price can be dived by the "scaling" number? it wont give any other suggestion. Any idea on this one? for example, the total price is 100, or 200, or 2000. it will give 3 same suggestion number as the total price

Comment: @Alvin: So for price=100 you want 101,110, 150 ?

Comment: @Alvin: And what would be the expected output for price=109?

Comment: yes Sir, any idea on how to combine it with previous answer? For the 109, it should be first suggestion starts from 110

Comment: the nextUp function will also return me 109.0 on price.nextUp.rounded(.up)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157874/discussion-between-martin-r-and-alvin).